# ReferenceError: File is not defined on Vercel deploy

Tags: next.js, vercel

Hi I'm trying to publish an app to vercel, but I get the following error: "ReferenceError: File is not defined".

```
ReferenceError: File is not defined
    at 1837 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/trpc/[trpc]/route.js:1:1693)
    at __webpack_require__ (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:146)
    at __webpack_exec__ (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/trpc/[trpc]/route.js:1:3490)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/trpc/[trpc]/route.js:1:3529
    at __webpack_require__.X (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1610)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/trpc/[trpc]/route.js:1:3503
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/trpc/[trpc]/route.js:1:3571)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/trpc/[trpc]
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1211:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

In my app I have this code, where the error path seems to be occurring:
/app/api/trpc/[trpc]/route.ts:

```
import { appRouter } from '../../../../trpc';
import { createTRPCContext } from '../../../../trpc/trpc';
import { fetchRequestHandler } from '@trpc/server/adapters/fetch';
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

// Handle TRPC endpoint requests
const handler = (req: NextRequest) =>
    fetchRequestHandler({
        endpoint: '/api/trpc',
        req,
        router: appRouter,
        createContext: () => createTRPCContext({ req }),
        onError: ({ error, path }) => {
            // Recived TRPC error
            console.error(` tRPC ERROR on '${path}'`, error);
        }
    });

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

But also, the error says route.js, when it actually is route.ts, what?

I have this same error in tow different projects, none of the have a reference "File" inside the Api route.
What's happening?

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, especially in file handling related to the File interface or FormData. I solved it by changing the NodeJS version on vercel 18.x to 20.x and redeployed the website again.

[ReferenceError: FIle isnt defined](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/56032#discussioncomment-7748375)